# How to use localStorage in nextJS client side

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, local-storage

I am getting an error when I try to get local storage data. I use the use client directive at the top but still the issue persists.

```
'use client';
const baseURL = 'https://localhost:7264';
const accessToken = localStorage.getItem('accessToken');


export async function GET(url, claim) {
    try {
        const res = await fetch(`${baseURL + url}`, {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                accessToken: accessToken,
                clientClaim: claim
            },
        });
        if (res.ok) {
            const data = res.json();
            return data;
        }
        return null;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);

        return null;
    }
}
```

Anyone helps me with how can I use localStorage in nextJS, specifically next 14

Comment: What exactly is the error?

Comment: The issue is that you are trying to get localStorage when at this point of time is undefined. one way to fix it will be, to add a useEffect inside the component - this will make sure the front end already rendered, means you can access localStorage... you will also need useState to store the token, and another useEffect to fire the request.

Comment: localStorage is undefined

Comment: The way you’re composing the file suggests it is a route handler. It cannot be run on a client and it’s executed on the server, hence it has no access to local storage. Slapping use client on a router file doesn’t do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume you're trying to define a [route handler](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-handlers) because of the name (`GET`) of the exported function and because of what it's doing.

---

Firstly, a [route handler](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-handlers) cannot have the `'use client'` directive because it is not a React component. This directive is used solely to mark certain components as client components rather than server ones.

---

Secondly, your route handler has the wrong parameters. Your handler is expecting a [`request`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request) parameter and you're passing `url` and `claim` separately.

---

Third, since you're trying to expose this as an API route, it does not make sense to try to access `localStorage` here to obtain an access key. This should be passed from the client through an [HTTP header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers) in the request. The server can access this from the [`request`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request) parameter.

---

Fourth, when using the `fetch` API, the [`response.json()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/json) method returns a Promise which you are returning directly instead of awaiting it.

---

Fifth, route handlers expect you to return a [`Response`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response) object and not the JSON object directly.

---

Given all these points, your handler should be something like:

```js
const baseURL = 'https://localhost:7264';

export async function GET(request) {
    const url = request.nextUrl.searchParams.get('url')
    const accessToken = request.headers.get('accessToken')
    const claim = request.headers.get('clientClaim')

    try {
        const res = await fetch(`${baseURL + url}`, {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                accessToken: accessToken,
                clientClaim: claim
            },
        });

        if (res.ok) {
            const data = await res.json();
            return Response.json(data);
        }

        return Response.json(null, { status: 500 });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);

        return Response.json(null, { status: 500 });
    }
}
```

With this handler, your client should consume it by passing `url` as a [search parameter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) and the access token and claim as headers `accessToken` and `clientClaim` respectively.